# Regular expressions to detect HTML attributes

Tags: regex, powershell

I need the simplest possible regular expression to find all text between the two quotes below **and** needs to be preceded with `<(input|select|textarea) name=`.

I am already able to search for all text between two quotation marks.  I am also able to find the preceding requirement shown above.  However, I can't combine the two.  Here's the closest I can come:

```
^\<(input|select|textarea) name\=[""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1$
```

Input lines:

```
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$LastName"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$email"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$phone"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><select name="MainPage$CountryDropDownList"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$Description"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><textarea name="MainPage$DescribeHere"..
```

Expected results:

```
MainPage$LastName
MainPage$email
MainPage$phone
MainPage$CountryDropDownList
MainPage$Description
MainPage$DescribeHere
```

Comment: Is that a single multi-line string, or an array of single line strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on some W3C forms tutorial pages and it found the desired elements:

```
$pattern = '(?is)<(input|select|textarea)\s+.*?(?:id|name)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"'
Select-String -inp $wr.RawContent -pattern $pattern -AllMatches | 
    Foreach {$_.Matches} | 
    Foreach {"Element: $($_.Groups[1].value) key: $($_.Groups[2].value)"}
```

Comment: Wow.  Nice.  You nailed it!  Could you please tell me where you found the tutorial?  I really need to understand all the stuff after -pattern LOL.  BTW:  Below is what I'm using now:  $r.RawContent | sls -pattern '(?is)<(input|select|textarea)\s+.*?(?:id|name)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"' -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches}
 | Foreach {"$($_.Groups[2].value)"}

Comment: I used this particular page for the select element: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select2

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=\<(input|select|textarea) name\=[\""|\']).*?(?=\"")
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Looks in there's a missing left parenthesis somewhere.  I'm getting an error complaining about  the right-parenthesis immediately before   .*?(?=\")

Comment: You might need to escape the quotes. Updated the answer for your benefit.

Comment: Yes, I already escaped all the single and double-quotes.  The regex above still gives an error about the right-paren for ....name\=[\""|\'])

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
(?:\<(input|select|textarea) name\=)(["'])(?<Name>.*)?\2
```

Your desired capture will be called `Name` and it ensures that the beginning quotes (whatever kind of quotation marks they are) match your end quotes.

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: I think there must be something incompatible when using that line above with Powershell.  It keeps complaining about an unexpected ')'    The right-paren for this:  (["'])

Comment: Weird, even with the escaping the quotes and your attempt to have matching parenthesis, it's still complaining about the same right paren for (["'])       .. This is what I'm trying to use currently:  (?:\<(input|select|textarea) name\=)(["'])(?<Name>.*)?\2

Comment: I really don't get it... Powershell uses the same libraries as .Net and this works there...

Comment: You're using the same exact regex above for .NET?  I thought .NET needs quotes escaped same as powershell.  The above example doesnt.  What did you use exactly to verify it works under .NET?  I'm sure I can find the equivalent under Powershell pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this:

```
$text = 
(@'
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$LastName"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$email"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$phone"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><select name="MainPage$CountryDropDownList"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$Description"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><textarea name="MainPage$DescribeHere"..
'@)


$regex = [regex]'(?:input|select|textarea)\sname="([^"]+)'

$regex.matches($text) |
foreach {$_.groups[1].value}

MainPage$LastName
MainPage$email
MainPage$phone
MainPage$CountryDropDownList
MainPage$Description
MainPage$DescribeHere
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my source is just a big block of raw html code as the variable $r.RawContent.  I dont think it even has `n at the end of each line.  So, the above example wouldn't really be the same as what I have.

Comment: OK.  I modified the regex, and switched to using the .matches() method.